# Brackets with given height

Tags: brackets

In some very very very restricted cases, "cum grano salis", I'd like to manually adjust some brackets heights.

The idea is to have a single macro that accepts an argument with the correct horizontal spacing like `\bigl`/`bigr` and similar. I only car about `()`, `[]` and `{}`. I tried:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BracketHeight}[1]{\bBigg@{#1}}%
\makeatletter

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BracketHeightlr}[1]{%
    \@ifnextchar({\mathopen\bBigg@{#1}}{%
    \@ifnextchar){\mathclose\bBigg@{#1}}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\mathopen\bBigg@{#1}}{%
    \@ifnextchar]{\mathclose\bBigg@{#1}}{%
    \@ifnextchar\{{\mathopen\bBigg@{#1}}{%
    \@ifnextchar\}{\mathclose\bBigg@{#1}}{\relax}}}}}}}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x&=\big(\times\big)\\
x&=\bigl(\times\bigr)\\
    x&=\BracketHeight{1}( \times \BracketHeight{1})\\
  x&=\BracketHeightlr{1}( \times \BracketHeightlr{1})
\end{align*}

\[
\BracketHeight{1}(
\BracketHeight{1.1}(
\BracketHeight{1.2}(
\BracketHeight{1.3}(
\BracketHeight{1.4}(
\BracketHeight{1.5}(
\BracketHeight{1.6}(
\BracketHeight{1.7}(
\BracketHeight{1.8}(
\BracketHeight{1.9}(
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that some values are "rounded".

Another idea is to write a macro that expands in:

```
\left NEXT BRACKET \rule{0pt}{#1cm}\right.
```

where `#1` is the argument given to the macro. E.g. `\BH{2}(` should expand to `\left(\rule{0pt}{#cm}\right.` and `\BH{2})` should expand to `\left.\rule{0pt}{2cm}\right)`. Honestly, this second idea does not convince me very much.

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: the font supplies a small set of delimiters at a fixed set of sizes, then the extendable version with the straight middle section, arbitrary sizes are not available

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand. If you like, please provide this comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font supplies a small set of delimiters at a fixed set of sizes, then the extendable version with the straight middle section, arbitrary sizes are not available.